# See filters for Google Inbox Finance/Purchases labels

Tags: gmail-labels, inbox-by-gmail

When checking settings of custom labels in Google Inbox, one can see the filters that are used to put emails there. However, such setting is not available for the special labels e.g. Purchases, Finance, Updates, etc.

Now, I do realize that there is a classifier underneath (unlike custom labels), but when an email is moved to the label, you are still being asked if all emails from this address should be moved there. It would be good to see which addresses were marked this way. Is it possible?

Comment: I expected this to be visible as a filter in Gmail interface. Indeed, [Google says](https://support.google.com/inbox/answer/6098273?hl=en): "When you [...] choose the "Always do this" option when moving emails, a filter will be created in Gmail." However, after testing this I did not find a filter for moving to Purchases; possibly because Gmail doesn't have Purchases category.

Answer (score 3):

Try these in the search bar(with clicking on the category name on the left side):

- `category:updates`
- `category:forums`
- `category:social`
- `category:promotions`

**Three special category**:

- Purchases  `category:^smartlabel_receipt`
- Finance  `category:^smartlabel_finance`
- Travel  `category:^smartlabel_travel`

Smart category is an experimental function of Gmail, seems no longer maintained.

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

It's not possible to see which addresses were marked to be bundled to one of the system-bundled labels like Purchases.

## Explanaition

Bundled labels criteria are not available to the user in the same way that Gmail filters are available through [Settings > Filters](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/filters) . By the other hand, some features of Inbox by Gmail doesn't work in the same way that the similar functions in Gmail.

## Alternatives

Review the email messages included in the desired system bundled labels.

## References

- [Organize your emails with bundled labels - Inbox by Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/inbox/answer/6050237?hl=en)
- [How Inbox works with Gmail - Inbox by Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/inbox/answer/6098273?hl=en)